# Extend GridColDef for MUI DataGrid

Tags: typescript, mui-x-data-grid, mui-x

I'm trying to extend MUI Data Grid column definition to include an additional parameter `"multiline"`.

I have look here: [Custom column types](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/column-definition/#custom-column-types) and here: [[data grid] Add column type to view and edit long text](https://github.com/mui/mui-x/issues/2851) but neither addresses my specific question directly.

What I'm trying to achieve is that in the column definition itself I'd like to add an additional paramemter:

```jsx
<DataGrid
  columns={[
    { field: 'status', type: 'string', multiline: false },
    { field: 'bio', type: 'string', multiline: true },
    // ...etc
  ]}
  rows={rows}
/>
```

While I am able to do exactly that, and it works as expected, I'm getting a TypeScript error that multiline doesn't exist on GridBaseColDef.

[image]

I tried extending  GridBaseColDef:

```ts
interface extendedGridColDef extends GridColDef {
  multiline?: boolean;
}
```

But now I'm getting an error saying that `An interface can only extend an object type or intersection of object types with statically known members`.

Any advice on how to resolve this?